# Is it natural to use "foul" instead of "polluted" and "to foul" instead of "to pollute"?

Tags: meaning, difference

according to [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/foul):
The verb "foul" can mean "pollute".
The adjective "foul" can mean "polluted", e.g. "foul air".
The adjective "foul" can mean "containing dirt, impurities, or other foreign matter", e.g. "foul water".

Did I understand correctly that instead of "polluted air/water" I can use "foul air/water"?

Comment: 'Foul' air or water are quite commonly discussed in the UK. Also the verb - only a fool fouls his own nest.

Comment: What context are you asking about? Sometimes "foul air/water" is used as a technical term, in which case you cannot replace one word with the other. Other times it's used simply to describe the water or air. So who's saying it and in what context is important.

Answer (score 2):

I find a slight difference, in that *polluted* means that something has been introduced that pollutes the air or water, (and also suggests that this has been done by some agent, either deliberately or carelessly).

*Foul* does not have this implication, for me.

I admit that it's a bit hard to come up with examples that are "foul" without being "polluted" in the sense that I mean it. In most cases there won't be an objective difference. But "polluted" draws attention to something that has been introduced.

Comment: In the UK, at any rate, in plumbing and drainage circles, 'foul water' is waste domestic or industrial waste water that has been contaminated or polluted with human waste, chemicals, etc. It is distinguished from 'surface water' which is usually just rainwater.

Comment: There's a difference between the adjectives "foul" (Containing dirt, impurities, or other foreign matter) and "fouled" (made dirty or foul).

Comment: In British English, a ***foul drain*** refers to the drainage system taking *household* waste water away. We wouldn't normally call the water in it "polluted" or "contaminated" - it's just that *in principle* if the water companies could keep that water separate from the *other* drainage system (domestic "run-off" rainwater falling on roofs, street drains, etc.), they could save money with less expensive water treatment processes for the latter. But in practice I think nearly all of it's been mixed together long before it even gets to the treatment plants.

Comment: "Foul" can refer to things that are decayed or rotten, which wouldn't be polluted by an external substance. Merriam-Webster mentions "the foul odor of rotten eggs". Pollute and pollution have a more precise meaning.

Comment: There is the transitive verb **foul** but it is used in the US most often when water has been made undrinkable not by man-made chemical pollutants but by animals.  *Don't drink from that  spring. It's been fouled by animals.*

Comment: This is from the British Parliament House of Commons in 1874: "...the ground is trodden into almost impassable sloughs by the cattle , and the water , even from the outlet of the spring , is indescribably fouled by their stalings and dung".

Comment: You described the difference between the adjectives "foul" and "polluted". Do the verbs "to foul" and "to pollute" have the same difference as the adjectives do?

Comment: The adjectives have a range of meanings, with some overlap.  But **foul** water isn't necessarily "polluted" whereas  all "polluted" water would be "foul" but it might not be perceived to be foul, if the pollutant is odorless and tasteless.

Comment: I do not regard **polluted** to be a plain and simple *adjective*. It is the past participle of the transitive verb "to pollute" used adjectivally, but implicit in the adjective is the notion of a pollutant and a polluter.  With **foul** there is not necessarily a befouler. Stagnant water can be foul.